# Material UI Avatar in card size not changing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hope you can help am trying to change the Avatar size in my card component and this does not work.

```
<Avatar
          

    alt="Remy Sharp"
              src="https://material-ui.com/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
              className={classes.large}
            />
```

I'm guessing it is because it is in the card component?
I even checked adding it in a code sandbox with a card form MUI and it didn't work there either.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give your code of Card component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the following.

#### Option 1

```
<Avatar
  alt="Remy Sharp"
  height={24}
  src="https://material-ui.com/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
  width={24}
/>
```

#### Option 2

```
<Avatar
  alt="Remy Sharp"
  classes={{ root: classes.large }}
  src="https://material-ui.com/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
/>
```

#### Option 3

```
const classes = useStyles(() => {
  return {
    large: {
      height: `24px !important`, // whatever height
      width: `24px !important`, // whatever height
    }, 
  };
});
```

```
<Avatar
  alt="Remy Sharp"
  className={classes.large}
  src="https://material-ui.com/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
/>
```

#### Option 4

```
const classes = useStyles(() => {
  return {
    card: {
      '& avatar': {
        height: 24, // whatever height
        width: 24, // whatever height
       },
    }, 
  };
});
```

```
  <Card className={classes.card}>
    <Avatar
      alt="Remy Sharp"
      className='avatar'
      src="https://material-ui.com/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
    />
  </Card>
```